# onPreferenceClick and OnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: android

I'm attempting to evaluate my preferences in my java code in order to enable/disable other options it they chose not to do other options... So far i'm trying to only implement the OnPreferenceClickListener however i never see the toast from the changes. What am i doing wrong? There seem to be alot of other questions like this but i cannot see my error in reference to them.

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener{
    SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    Boolean frequency;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        frequency = mPreferences.getBoolean("frequency", true);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast 0!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (!frequency) {
            Context context2 = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context2, "Hello toast 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (preference.getKey().equals("schedulestop")) {

        } else if (preference.getKey().equals("priority")) {

        } else {
            Context context3 = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context3, "Hello toast 0!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you get access for `getApplicationContext()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register for PreferenceClickListener each individual preference

```
somePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```

or you can use `getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` for all preferences.

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
SharedPreferences mPreferences;
Boolean frequency;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("schedulestop")) {
         // do something
     }
     else if (key.equals(......
}
}
```

Comment: Is that set on the onCreate?

Comment: In onCreate or onStart or onResume and unregister in onDestroy, onStop or onPause.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to implement it straight into my code. Looking at examples i'm not seeing how to do it without errors.

Answer (score 1):

**first implement "OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener"**

```
PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

**Then**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}
```

**THEN**

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    switch (key) {
        case "pref_key_auto_delete":
            boolean notificationStatus = SP.getBoolean(key, false);
            Log.d("stat", String.valueOf(notificationStatus));
            break;

        case "pref_key_notification_list":
            String downloadType = SP.getString(key, "n/a");
            Log.d("stat", String.valueOf(downloadType));
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Though off-topic, I didn't know that we could use the switch statement for Strings in java!