# Custom Preference - Button not clickable

Tags: android, android-fragments, preference

I'm working on a settings screen and I'm using Android's Preference API to build the interface. 
One of the preference will be a button - and I've done it by adding a custom layout to the preference. It works - the button is displayed as I want it but the problem is that when setting OnPreferenceClickListener nothing happens. It's not triggered.

I've tried adding beforeDescendants on the button layout root but no luck. Also tried to add focusable false to the button but still no luck.

Can anyone please share some tips on how I can make the preference button respond?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449372/onpreferenceclick-and-onpreferenceclicklistener) answer ?

Comment: I don't know how is this related?

Comment: "You have to register for PreferenceClickListener each individual preference
somePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);" I would also suggest posting your code

Comment: I'm doing this. I already said that I'm setting OnPreferenceClickListener on this preference but when clicking the button nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried before calling the Listener to enable your button? `myButton.setEnabled(true); `

Comment: Isn't the button enabled by default?

Comment: Please post your code for the preference. Also, can you replicate this issue with as simple as possible code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onPreferenceClick is triggered when the Prefererence has been clicked not when you click the button. If you want to catch the button click you need to set a OnClickListener on the button itself. The problem is to retrieve the inflated button since the Preference class doesn't have a findViewById method or anything similar. Here's how I'd do it:

1. Create a custom Preference class and override the onCreateView
2. In the onCreateView method you grab the inflated layout from the super class and find the Button
3. Add an OnClickListener to the button
4. Use your custom Preference class in your preference layout file

> 

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference  {

    public CustomPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View preferenceView = super.onCreateView(parent);

        setOnClickListener(preferenceView);

        return preferenceView;
    }

    private void setOnClickListener(View preferenceView) {
        if (preferenceView != null && preferenceView instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup widgetFrameView = ((ViewGroup)preferenceView.findViewById(android.R.id.widget_frame));
            if (widgetFrameView != null) {
                // find the button
                Button theButton = null;
                int count = widgetFrameView.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    View view = widgetFrameView.getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button) {
                        theButton = (Button)view;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (theButton != null) {
                    // set the OnClickListener
                    theButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // do whatever you want to do
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This replaces the Preference in your xml file:

```
<yourpackage.CustomPreference
    android:key="your_id"
    android:title="@string/your_title"
    android:summary="@string/your_summary"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something similar to the code below to implement this:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView (ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences_station_list_row, null);
    ((ImageButton) customRow.findViewById(R.id.pref_delete_station)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //perform whatever you need to button to do here.
        }
    });

    customRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(null);
        }
    });
    customRow.setClickable(true);
    return customRow;
}
```

Has this solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Override the '[onClick()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onClick())' from [Preference](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) method and make sure your custom layout **does NOT have**:

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

You don't need anything else special, but if your layout contains a view with *android:clickable="true"* it messes it up completely.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Emanuel Moecklin 's answer, in 2022 androidx Preference you can use:

```
class FooterPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): Preference(context, attrs) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        holder?.itemView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)?.setOnClickListener {
            Timber.d("button clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

```
<packageName.FooterPreference
        app:layout="@layout/layout_preference_footer" />
```